# Pandas: how to apply function to column names

Tags: python, pandas

I would like all columns to be named in a uniform manner, like:

```
Last Name -> LAST_NAME
e-mail -> E_MAIL
ZIP code 2 -> ZIP_CODE_2
```

For that purpose I wrote a function that uppercases all symbols, keeps digits and replaces rest of the characters with underscore (`'_'`). Then it replaces multiple underscores with just one and trims underscores at both ends.

How do I apply this function (lambda) to the column names in *Pandas*?

Answer (score 22):

You can do this without using `apply` by calling the vectorised `str` methods:

```
In [62]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Last Name','e-mail','ZIP code 2'])
df.columns

Out[62]:
Index(['Last Name', 'e-mail', 'ZIP code 2'], dtype='object')

In [63]:    
df.columns = df.columns.str.upper().str.replace(' ','_')
df.columns    

Out[63]:
Index(['LAST_NAME', 'E-MAIL', 'ZIP_CODE_2'], dtype='object')
```

Otherwise you can convert the `Index` object to a `Series` using `to_series` so you can use `apply`:

```
In [67]:
def func(x):
    return x.upper().replace(' ','_')
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().apply(func)
df

Out[67]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [LAST_NAME, E-MAIL, ZIP_CODE_2]
Index: []
```

Thanks to @PaulH for suggesting using `rename` with a `lambda`:

```
In [68]:
df.rename(columns=lambda c: c.upper().replace(' ','_'), inplace=True)
df.columns

Out[68]:
Index(['LAST_NAME', 'E-MAIL', 'ZIP_CODE_2'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply set the `.columns` property of the data frame. So in order to rename it, you can use:

```
df.columns = list(map(yourlambda,df.columns))
```

Where you of course replace **`yourlambda`** with your lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ***list comprehension***. For example, here is how you can leave only 5 characters of the names of the columns:

```
df.columns = [col[0:6] for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: I like this. More generally:

`df.columns = [myfunc(col) for col in df.columns]`