# Rename all DataFrame columns using a callable

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

I'm loading a CSV file into a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrame but the headers of the columns contain accented letter (éüöà...), blanks, and also sometimes special characters such as slashes, percent signs, the dollar signs, brackets, etc.

**Without knowing the column names in advance**, is there a method for converting special characters to a valid one, e.g. underscore "_" and to convert accented letters to their English version (i.e. without accent) so that, when inserting the DataFrame into a [PostgreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) database, the database fields do not need to be double quoted?

For the moment, I've simply build a small function which convert any string into a "normal" form:

```py
import re
from unidecode import unidecode

def standarize_str(mystring):
    mystring = unidecode(mystring, errors='replace', replace_str='_')
    mystring = re.sub('[^A-Za-z-_0-9]', '_', mystring)
    
    return mystring
```

But I don't know if it's possible to use it as a **callable** onto the columns of my DataFrame?
Or -- what I'm currently doing -- if I should loop over `df.colums` to build the necessary `dict` to replace all the columns with their standardized names?

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788311/pandas-how-to-apply-function-to-column-names) doesn't answer my question because answers are about:

- list comprehension (which, as I said, I currently do as a workaround)
- `str` methods, which doesn't allow the user to use a custom function
- lambda (which I don't want to use)

So instead of using all these, I really want to be able to use something more pythonic such as: `df.rename_with_callable(standarize_str)`